# Cleaning up captcha image use OpenCV

Tags: ios, image, opencv, tesseract, captcha

How to clear the captcha picture of the interference line, when the interference line and the text of the same color

I try to use the following picture as a demo

[demo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1gkR.png)

Use the following code processing

```
- (UIImage *)cleanLine:(UIImage *)image {

   IplImage *src = [self convertToIplImage:image];

   IplImage *gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
   IplImage *dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
   IplImage *binary = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

   cvCvtColor(src, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
   cvThreshold(gray, binary, 120, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);

   findLines(gray, dst);

for (int row = 0; row < binary->height; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < binary->width; col++)
    {
        if (cvGet2D(dst, row, col).val[0] == 255)
        {
            int up = 0, down = 0;
            int white = 0;
            for (int i = row; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (cvGet2D(binary, i, col).val[0] == 0)
                {
                    up++;
                    white = 0;
                }
                else white++;
                if(white > 2)    break;
            }
            white = 0;
            for (int i = row; i < binary->height; i++)
            {
                if (cvGet2D(binary, i, col).val[0] == 0)
                {
                    down++;
                    white = 0;
                }
                else white++;
                if (white > 2)   break;
            }
            if (up + down < 8)
            {
                for (int i = -up; i <= down; i++) cvSet2D(binary, row + i, col, cvScalar(255));
            }
        }
    }

    erase(binary);

    cvErode(binary, binary, NULL, 1);

    cvDilate(binary, binary, NULL, 1);

    Mat Img = cvarrToMat(binary);

    cvReleaseImage(&src);
    cvReleaseImage(&gray);
    cvReleaseImage(&dst);
    cvReleaseImage(&binary);

    return MatToUIImage(Img); 
}
```

Find the line of interference code

```
void findLines(IplImage *raw, IplImage *dst) {

IplImage *src = cvCloneImage(raw);
IplImage *canny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

cvCanny(src, canny, 20, 200, 3);
CvMemStorage *stor = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq *lines = NULL;

lines = cvHoughLines2(canny, stor, CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, 1, CV_PI / 180, 80, 200, 30);
cvZero(dst);

CvPoint maxStart, maxEnd;

int maxDistance = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < lines->total; i++) {
    CvPoint* line = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(lines, i);
    if (abs(line[0].x - line[1].x) > maxDistance) {
        maxDistance = abs(line[0].x - line[1].x);
        maxStart = line[0];
        maxEnd = line[1];
    }
}

cvLine(dst, maxStart, maxEnd, cvScalar(255), 1);

cvReleaseImage(&src);
cvReleaseMemStorage(&stor);
}
```

Get the result picture [result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r59hh.png)

I have a part of the captcha image here 
[captcha image](https://github.com/lu469814/TestImage/files/1777313/OCR_Img.zip)

I used my code to process the captcha image, but it did not work

I do not know how to modify my code to make it clear the interference line

Anyone can guide me, thank you very much

Comment: I would suggest to use [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). It will be helpful...

Comment: I tried using tesseract, if you do not first deal with the picture, the recognition rate is very low